# getting double quotes around every element of list

Tags: python

I'm stuck in some weird problem

I'm creating list from below json

```
    op = {'specific' : {
            'run' : {
               'name': 'jon',
               'location':'NY'
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my code

```
 lst = []
 jsn = op['specific']
 for task in jsn:
     for attrs in jsn[task]:
         lst.append[ [[task, attrs], jsn[task][attrs]] ]
 return lst
```

Now when I'm passing this list to another location to process, before processing, its being accessed like in this format

```
("[[['run','name'],'jon'],"
"[[['run','location'],'NY'],")
```

I'm kind of stuck how its happening ? not able to think any way out of this. If someone wants to know, where its being send to process further, that is, one operator output to another operator in Airflow, but I'm able to see correct output in operator one, but the time I only access it to second operator, it becomes in above format(before processing)

Can anyone suggest, what can be tried to solve this or debug this ?

mentioned above, please check

Comment: That's not valid json. You probably want `op = { 'specific': ...}`. How are you passing this to another process? What is that other process?

Comment: `lst.append[]` will throw an error. Do you actually have `lst.append()`?

Comment: @JonSG, correct, typo error

Comment: If you fix the `append()` statement, you code produce that output that is then getting cast to a string someplace. If you want to get it back as a list of lists take what you have and apply `ast.literal_eval()` on it

Comment: Please don't call this JSON. JSON has stricter syntax rules than Python has for *dictionary* literals. What you have there is valid Python, but not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing some of the typos in your code, as:

```py
op = {
    'specific' : {
        'run' : {
           'name': 'jon',
           'location':'NY'
        }
    }
}

def work(op):
    lst = []
    jsn = op['specific']
    for task, task_values in jsn.items():
        for attrs, attr_values in task_values.items():
            lst.append([[task, attrs], attr_values])
    return lst

print(work(op))
```

The output you get is something like:

```
[
    [
        ['run', 'name'],
        'jon'
    ],
    [
        ['run', 'location'],
        'NY'
    ]
]
```

I assume that by the time your second process gets this result, it has been cast to a string:

```
"[[['run', 'name'], 'jon'], [['run', 'location'], 'NY']]"
```

And what you seek to do is cast that string back into a list of lists...

To do that, I would use the `ast` package, specifically `ast.literal_eval()`

```
import ast
l_o_l = ast.literal_eval("[[['run', 'name'], 'jon'], [['run', 'location'], 'NY']]")
print(l_o_l)
```

That should give you back your original result.